# Sort arr by nested sub-array

Tags: javascript, sorting, underscore.js

This is my arr:

```
var arr = [
    {
        "name": "ASD",
        "properties": [
            {
                "name": "TypeId",
                "nominalValue": "AC101"
            },
            {
                "name": "Description",
                "nominalValue": "text here"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "EWQ",
        "properties": [
            {
                "name": "TypeId",
                "nominalValue": "AB123"
            },
            {
                "name": "Description",
                "nominalValue": "text here"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to sort it by give a `name` in the properties arr and it returns it sorted by the `nominalValue`

Like this:

```
var sortedArr = sortListByPropertyName(arr, 'TypeId'); //Sorts list by 'AB123', 'AC101'..
```

My dataset is quite big so it's important to do it as optimized as possible. Can I use `_.sortBy` with some clever `chains` maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
function sortListByPropertyName(arr, propName) {
  return _.sortBy(arr, function(obj) {
    return
    _.find(obj.properties, function(prop) {
      return prop.name == propName
    }).nominalValue;
  });
}
```